# Webscraping images through py jupyter

Tags: python, html, image, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape images from this url through py in jupyter: https://www.adobe.com/products/catalog.html?sort=name&types=pf_252Fdesktop&types=pf_252Fmobile&types=pf_252Fweb&page=1, but when ran the code below I got this error:

```
import requests from bs4 
import BeautifulSoup 
# download page page = "adobe.com/products/…" result = requests.get(page) 
# if successful parse the download into a BeautifulSoup object, which allows easy manipulation 
if result.status_code == 200: soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, "html.parser")
```

`Error: SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.adobe.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /products/catalog.html?sort=name&types=pf_252Fdesktop&types=pf_252Fmobile&types=pf_252Fweb&page=1 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))`

Any suggestion on fixing the error what root problem?
Thanks

Comment: It would help if you provided some sample code of how you are currently trying to achieve this. It is failing at properly establishing the SSL connection, but without any code, we cannot help debug. You might also want to make sure this activity is indeed following robots.txt and any copyright.

Comment: Thanks, this is my code so far: import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# download page
page = "https://www.adobe.com/products/catalog.html?sort=date&types=pf_252Fdesktop&types=pf_252Fmobile&types=pf_252Fweb&page=1"
result = requests.get(page)

# if successful parse the download into a BeautifulSoup object, which allows easy manipulation 
if result.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, "html.parser")

Answer (score 0):

```
In [23]: res = requests.get("https://www.adobe.com/products/catalog.html?sort=name&types=pf_252Fdesktop&types=pf_252Fm
    ...: obile&types=pf_252Fweb&page=1", verify=False)
/Users/abhilash.kr/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1004: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning,

In [24]: res
Out[24]: <Response [200]>
```

You need to use `verify=False` in your `get` method